# Battery level inaccurate, and calibrating won't work

Tags: battery, hp-pavilion

Here are my specs: http://speccy.piriform.com/results/3lNpVlcoGq2HddapQBCzGvG

Whenever my battery reaches around 40%, it shuts down, as if out of battery. I cannot turn it on until charging it again. But when plugging it back in, it once again says my battery isn't out, but only at around 40%.

Battery level also jumps around constantly, change from 70 to 0 and back to 70 within a minute.

Running a battery check says that it is okay.

What is the issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: You say calibrating won't work.  What procedures have you tried?

Comment: I have tried draining battery all the way and refilling it, as described here: http://www.howtogeek.com/172271/how-to-calibrate-your-laptops-battery-for-accurate-battery-life-estimates/

Comment: Is the exact model of your laptop - hp pavilion g6 103c? Your specs only mention the type of computer: notebook.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure if the battery is good or bad, test how long it lasts from 40% charge down to 0% (drained).

Most probably, the battery has at least one dead pair of cells. That pair will not be able to charge (and can also overheat and trigger thermal shutdown) and the good-most pair will try to overcharge and also cause overheat / thermal protection shutdown.

Comment: It gets down, and constantly jumps around. It says 40, then shuts down, then after charging it it says 70, then 0, then back to 70

Comment: If you don't have any more warranty for the battery, just open it up enough to measure the voltage on the cell pairs. Also, you could test it on an identical device if anyone can provide one for you.